# Why width isn't the same VideoCapture(1) and VideoCapture(-1)?

Tags: java, opencv

I am using VideoCapture to open my webcam. First I used VideoCapture(1) because the webcam I was using was the second in my computer.
But now, I am adding a new feature, and I want to choose which camera have to be open. So I am using VideoCapture(-1), but the width of the frame isn't the same do you know why ?
This is my code

```
        webSource = new VideoCapture(1);
        webSource.set(CAP_PROP_FPS, 24);
        webSource.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,1280);
        webSource.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,960);
```

when I am using this one, the number of cols is 960 but when I am using the other one :

```
        webSource = new VideoCapture(-1);
        webSource.set(CAP_PROP_FPS, 24);
        webSource.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,1280);
        webSource.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,960);
```

and if I select the same webcam, the number of cols is 640.
I don't know why, someone can explain it to me ?

Lucas

Comment: why did you choose -1???

Comment: @Micka because it opens a window where all the webcam pluged are, and i can choose the one i want

Comment: cool, I didn't know that yet.